# Восстановить файлы когда "fatal: loose object" после rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

После проблем с диском после `rebase` получаю при почти любых командах Гита:

```
error: object file .git/objects/ba/b662584e1722e1ad97ed330282fe30f871b2e4 is empty
error: object file .git/objects/ba/b662584e1722e1ad97ed330282fe30f871b2e4 is empty
fatal: loose object bab662584e1722e1ad97ed330282fe30f871b2e4 (stored in .git/objects/ba/b662584e1722e1ad97ed330282fe30f871b2e4) is corrupt
```

При этом файлы, которые я добавлял в своей ветке есть, но они пусты.

Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основано на реальных событиях.

Если вам повезло, то предыдущее состояние ветки всё ещё где-то в директориях Гита. Возможная последовательность действий:

#### Сделать бэкап

**Обязательно** сделайте бэкап рабочей папки.

#### Пройтись по списку объектов

git-reflog и git-rev-list в моём случае не работали. Поэтому я использовал git-cat-file:

```
git cat-file --batch-check --batch-all-objects
```

Это сработало. Осталось пройти по объектам, которые являются коммитами и найти свой, например по коммит-мессаджу:

```
for i in $(git cat-file --batch-check --batch-all-objects | grep commit | awk '{ print $1; }')
do
  git show --pretty='%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s' $i | head -1
done
```

Вывот от этого отправляем в grep. В моём случае, чтобы найти задачу 123:

```
grep 'refs #123' -- all-objects.txt
```

Выведет несколько коммитов. По каждому надо пройтись git-show.

```
git show 0751ce2
```

Если это то, поздравляю, мы почти на месте.

#### Сделать патч и применить на здоровой репе

Для каждого из нужных коммитов делаем

```
git show 0751ce2 > 0751ce2.patch
```

Клоним в новую папку здоровую репу и применяем:

```
git apply -p 1 0751ce2.patch
```

После этого осталось проверить, что всё на месте и закоммититься.